# Yii get all databases

Tags: yii

I'm trying to get all databases in my Yii application.
My very first solution is as follows:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host = localhost; dbname=myDBname";
$username = "myUsername";
$password = "myPassword";

$command = "show databases";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->query($command);
var_dump($db->query($command)->fetchAll()) ;
```

However, I understand that this solution doesn't take advantage of the framework. So I try looking for a better way, and that may look like this:

```
        $sql = "show databases";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $result = $command->query();
        var_dump($result);
```

With this way, however, the result is not as I expected. It actually returns an object instance of CDbDataReader class. and the property to access the real PDO object is kept private (its name is "_statement") so I cann't access it to fetch all databases.
So, could you help me find a more elegant way that can get more from the Yii framework that the first solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got answer, I just have to change "query" method to "queryAll" so it looks something like that:
var_dump(Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SHOW DATABASES')->queryAll());